# I think I broke my elytra

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a race between me and my brother, and one part is from getting to one place to another by elytra and a rocket. His works like it should, but I just fall, even when spamming them in creative mode. My brother is an eye witness to this and we were both shocked, since our favorite way to travel is by elytra. We're both in version 1.13.1 of Minecraft and I'm hosting a LAN world for him to join. Can anyone help me, or am I just going to have to take the rockets out of our race?

Comment: Is there any way we can duplicate the issue on our end?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely either [this bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-111480) (first world you join after starting the game has issues) or [this bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-92916) (after teleporting a long distance, you get issues) or any of the related ones. Exiting and re-joining the world should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a normal thing where the elytra runs out of durability. You can repair it with another damged elytra, or you can get another one. If the elytra looks tattered, then that means it has 1 durability left (they never break, but you can't use it when it has 1 durability left)